# Send Keys to Different Window

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

I want to send keys to another window followed by the enter key.
I have tried researching on google and have found no luck. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`SendKeys(...)` only sends to the active window, so you can not use it with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You could try P/Invoking `PostMessage(...)` with `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`.